# Is there a rule for the stressed part in the word in the imperative mood?

Tags: verbs, pronunciation

Sometimes I'm confused in pronouncing the words in the imperative mood.
For example:

> Alzarsi (3 syllables) -> **a**lzati (1st syllable is stressed, 3
> syllables)
>
> Lavarsi (3 syllables) -> **la**vati (1st syllable is stressed, 3
> syllables)
>
> Svegliarsi (3 syllables) -> **sve**gliati (1st syllable is stressed, 3
> syllables)

OK, clear, but:

> Pulirsi (3 syllables) -> pu**li**sciti (2nd syllable is stressed, 4
> syllables)
>
> Pettinarsi (4 syllables) -> **pe**ttinati (1st syllable is stressed, 3
> syllables)

Is there any rule based on syllables, where to put the stress?

Comment: Just a side note: when talking about the stressed syllables, what matters is the count from the *end* of the word, not from the beginning. So, for example, "***sve**gliati" and "*pu**li**sciti*" belong to the same group because the stress is on the *third **to last*** syllable

Comment: @secan thank you

Answer (score 4):

Long not-quite-an-answer, actually.

First of all, in general in Italian you count the syllables from the end, rather than from the beginning. So, most words are *piane*, that is, the (main) stress is to the last-but-one syllable. The words *casa*, *lavoro*, *panettone* all belong to the same category, even though the stressed syllables are, respectively, the first, the second, and the third one.

Secondly, all your examples are of verbs with a clitic pronoun attached at the end, which muddles things a little. The good news is that the stress in the verb itself doesn't move: *làva* > *làvati*; *pulìsci* > *pulìsciti* and so on. (Accents are not usually written down, but I'm writing them here for clarity.)

So we are left with just the “pure” form of the imperative mood: *lava*, *pulisci* etc. (All the examples in the question are in the 2nd (singular) person, but the imperative mood also has a 5th (or 2nd plural) person: *lavate*, *pulite* and so on.)

In modern Italian, in most cases, these forms are equal to the 3rd person (for the verbs in *-are*) or the 2nd person (for the verbs in *-ere* or in *-ire*) the  in the present of the indicative mood:

> (*lui*) *lava* = he washes; *lava!* = wash!
> (*tu*) *tieni* = you hold; *tieni!* = *hold!*
> (*tu*) *pulisci* = you clean; *pulisci!* = *clean!*

So the problem reduces to learning how to conjugate in the present tense of the indicative mood a given verb, and this is mostly regular (according to the different classes of verbs) and is anyway easy to find for specific verbs in any dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.